# Javascript show up on webpage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code in a Visual Studio aspx web page i'm building

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function printdiv(printpage) {
    var headstr = '<html><head><title></title></head><body>';
    var footstr = '</body>';
    var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
    var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
    return false;
}
</script>
<script runat="server">
    'VB-code follows here
```

If i run it locally on my computer to test it, everything works fine, both the javascript and vb code runs all right.
However, when i upload it to my server and test it, only the VB will run and on the top of the page the following plain text is visible:

'; var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML; var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML; document.body.innerHTML = headstr + newstr + footstr; window.print(); document.body.innerHTML = oldstr; return false; }